# Neo4j Is it possible to use 2 CALL apoc.merge.relationship calls in one cypher script?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

If you have 3 nodes and two relationships is it possible to use 2 `CALL apoc.merge.relationship` calls in one cypher script?

For example you have 3 merge calls to grab data from a csv:

```
MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From})
MERGE (b:Url { name: row.Url_Sub_Fld})
MERGE (c:Recipient { name: row.To})
```

then a with:

```
WITH a,b,c,row
```

then 2 `apoc.merge.relationship(` calls

```
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome, {}, {}, b)
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(b, row.Outcome, {}, {}, c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though you do need to include at least one YIELDed variable from each call. Since this is the same procedure being called, you'll need to alias the yielded variables so you don't get a collision.

```
...
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome, {}, {}, b) YIELD rel as rel1
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(b, row.Outcome, {}, {}, c) YIELD rel as rel2
```